# KVM internal error suberror 1 when filling the CR3 register

Tags: x86-64, paging, kvm, osdev, uefi

I'm working on a x64 uefi bootloader to load a hobby OS. I'm running on AMD (Ryzen 7 5700G) with kvm, and when I try to fill the CR3 register with my PML4, I get a KVM internal error with 5 extra data

```
BdsDxe: failed to load Boot0001 "UEFI QEMU DVD-ROM QM00003 " from PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x1,0x1)/Ata(Secondary,Master,0x0): Not Found
BdsDxe: loading Boot0002 "UEFI QEMU HARDDISK QM00001 " from PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x1,0x1)/Ata(Primary,Master,0x0)
BdsDxe: starting Boot0002 "UEFI QEMU HARDDISK QM00001 " from PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x1,0x1)/Ata(Primary,Master,0x0)
Booting Helios x86_64 via EFI from 0x3df6e990
0x0: boot services code (1 pages)
0x1000: conventional memory (159 pages)
0x100000: conventional memory (1792 pages)
0x808000: conventional memory (3 pages)
0x80c000: conventional memory (4 pages)
0x1600000: conventional memory (238965 pages)
0x3bb95000: conventional memory (9176 pages)
0x3dfbe000: conventional memory (5 pages)
0x3e1cc000: conventional memory (3 pages)
0x3fe00000: conventional memory (119 pages)
Image base: 0x3df6d000
Load kernel /helios
Exit boot services
pml4 0x3df79000
ptpd 0x3df7a000
pd_ident 0x3df7b000
filling cr3
KVM internal error. Suberror: 1
extra data[0]: 0x0000000000000000
extra data[1]: 0x0000000000000400
extra data[2]: 0x0000000100000014
extra data[3]: 0x00000003de16e000
extra data[4]: 0x0000000000000000
extra data[5]: 0x0000000000000000
emulation failure
RAX=000000003df79000 RBX=0000000000000000 RCX=000000003f1175a0 RDX=0000000000000000
RSI=000000003e1d6420 RDI=000000003e1d5018 RBP=000000003fe967b0 RSP=000000003fe96770
R8 =000000000000000d R9 =00000000000003f8 R10=0000000000000003 R11=0000000000000000
R12=0000000000000000 R13=0000000000000000 R14=000000003e1e1298 R15=000000003dfbe018
RIP=000000003df6eeed RFL=00000202 [-------] CPL=0 II=0 A20=1 SMM=0 HLT=0
ES =0030 0000000000000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
CS =0038 0000000000000000 ffffffff 00a09b00 DPL=0 CS64 [-RA]
SS =0030 0000000000000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
DS =0030 0000000000000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
FS =0030 0000000000000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
GS =0030 0000000000000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
LDT=0000 0000000000000000 0000ffff 00008200 DPL=0 LDT
TR =0000 0000000000000000 0000ffff 00008b00 DPL=0 TSS64-busy
GDT=     000000003f5dc000 00000047
IDT=     000000003f13b018 00000fff
CR0=80010033 CR2=0000000000000000 CR3=000000003df79000 CR4=00000678
DR0=0000000000000000 DR1=0000000000000000 DR2=0000000000000000 DR3=0000000000000000 
DR6=00000000ffff0ff0 DR7=0000000000000400
EFER=0000000000000d00
Code=?? ?? ?? ?? ?? ?? ?? ?? ?? ?? ?? ?? ?? ?? ?? ?? ?? ?? ?? ?? <??> ?? ?? ?? ?? ?? ?? ?? ?? ?? ?? ?? ?? ?? ?? ?? ?? ?? ?? ?? ?? ?? ?? ?? ?? ?? ?? ?? ?? ??
```

I don't understand what the 5 `extra data` fields represent. I tried to run the same code on Intel (Ivy Bridge) and it runs without any issue. I also tried adding the `Global` bit, but I end up stalling at the same place, without the interal error report.

Here's the function in question, it's called right after `BootServices->ExitBootServices`

```
#include <stddef.h>
#include "bprintf.h"
#include "mmu.h"

#define PT_P    (1 << 0)
#define PT_RW   (1 << 1)
#define PT_US   (1 << 2)
#define PT_PS   (1 << 7)
#define PT_G    (1 << 8)

#define CR4_PSE (1 << 4)
#define CR4_PGE (1 << 7)

// TODO: Add dynamic virtual address space mappings here and load the kernel
// properly with the appropriate flags and such
#define IDENT_PDS   64

__attribute__((aligned(4096))) static uintptr_t pml4[512] = {0};
__attribute__((aligned(4096))) static uintptr_t pdpt[512] = {0};
__attribute__((aligned(4096))) static uintptr_t pd_ident[IDENT_PDS * 512] = {0};

void
init_mmu()
{
    asm("cli");

    bprintfln("pml4 %p", &pml4);
    bprintfln("ptpd %p", &pdpt);
    bprintfln("pd_ident %p", &pd_ident);

    unsigned long cr4;
    asm("mov %%cr4, %%rax" : "=a"(cr4));
    asm volatile("mov %%rax, %%cr4" ::"a"(cr4 | CR4_PSE));

    /* Map first 64GiB of physical memory at -512GiB to -448GiB */
    pml4[511] = (uintptr_t)&pdpt | PT_P | PT_RW | PT_US;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < IDENT_PDS; i++)
        pdpt[i] = (uintptr_t)&pd_ident[i*512] | PT_P | PT_RW | PT_US;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < IDENT_PDS * 512; i++)
        pd_ident[i] = (i * 0x2000000UL) | PT_P | PT_RW | PT_US | PT_PS;

    /* Map the first 1GiB physical to the last 1GiB virtual */
    pdpt[511] = (uintptr_t)&pd_ident[0] | PT_P | PT_RW | PT_US;

    /* EFI environment identity maps the lower half, preserve that here. */
    pml4[0] = (uintptr_t)&pdpt | PT_P | PT_RW | PT_US;

    bprintfln("filling cr3");
    asm volatile("movq %0, %%cr3" : : "r"(&pml4) : "memory");
    bprintfln("init_mmu() done");
}
```

Comment: A few things to check: (1) you're already in long mode, so paging is already enabled when you get here, right?  Then you're loading `cr3` with the *virtual* address of `pml4`, so are you sure that you're accessing it through an identity mapping?

Comment: (3) Maybe unrelated, but if I read the docs correctly, the PSE bit doesn't do anything when in long mode.  Why are you setting it?

Comment: I think there is a typo in your arithmetic where you populate the page tables.  You presumably want them at 2 MB intervals (0x200000) but you are using 32 MB (0x2000000).

Comment: (1) UEFI guarantees that long mode is set (see 2.3.4. x64 Platforms). (2) The address of the PML4 should be correct, as stated it works on intel cpus. (3) I havent seen anything about that, but I'll double check.
Thanks for the typo, I hit `unhandled IRQ 0` after the exit of the function, I think that was my issue!